# RAM mystery - Why show debain 3.2 but ubuntus 4 GiB RAM

Tags: ubuntu, memory, debian

I have read a lot of different speculations on the web, some say 32bit OS can use only 3.2GIB other say its used by the kernel...

I have 2x 2048 RAM on my laptop.

In *debian* the *free* command shows 3358224 total Mem. (System Monitor shows 3.2 GiB).
In all *ubuntu* versions its around  4122660 (System Monitor shows 3.9 GiB)

Can *debian* use only 3.2GiB RAM ?

```
user@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-7-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-1 (2018-07-05) i686 GNU/Linux 

mint@mint:~$ uname -a
Linux mint 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:15:38 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Which versions of `Debian` and `Ubuntu` are you using? Even as your hardware is 64 bits, is it possible that you are using Debian 32 bits?

Comment: Please provide the output of `uname -a` from both operating systems.

Comment: my hardware is  32 bits (laptop from 2009). Yet I am testing  live versions to decide what I shall install. the 18.04 Ubuntus take exremly long to boot, debian is fast I can not decide...

Comment: I think Ubuntu is using a kernel with PAE and your Debian isn't.

Comment: @Daniel *user@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-7-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-1 (2018-07-05) i686 GNU/Linux*

Comment: @Daniel *mint@mint:~$ uname -a Linux mint 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:15:38 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux*

Comment: Please [add this information to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1358105/edit).

Comment: As @GabrielaGarcia says, mint's (ubuntu's) kernel should be PAE enabled

Comment: Is there a way to change (or to update) the kernel to PAE mode in Debian ? I have no idea about that.

Comment: `apt install linux-image-4.9.0-7-686-pae`

Comment: Also note that the difference might be just in calculating the sizes: using [gibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) vs SI's [gigabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte).

Comment: I just saw the CPU is x86_64 type :) So if I use an amd64.iso will it use the full RAM? And the hole OS  will be faster? it is a Fujitsu Siemens Lifebook E8310

Comment: @kostix That can't possibly account for so much difference. 3.2 GiB would display is only 3.4 GB.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia You should enlarge that to an answer, with discussion of PAE's role.

Comment: @Asklep Just having an x64 CPU doesn't mean the OS is 64 bits. Even with a 64-bit OS (which will include PAE-like behavior) the firmware would still have to be set to implement memory hole remapping, in order to use all 4 GiB installed. Without memory hole remapping, RAM that would conflict with I/O address space is just not accessible.

Comment: (Sorry to excavate this old thread, but still.) You may install the `-amd64` kernel and still have 32-bit (i386) userspace. To do this, you first run `dpkg --add-architecture amd64` (as root) and then install the `linux-image-amd64` package. Then reboot and select this image from the GRUB menu. If it boots and works OK, you may remove all the `linux-image*-i686` packages. This approach has an upside in that the kernel using the native CPU instruction set works faster.